# How do I remove the annoying Authenticator(Terminal)?

Tags: password, steam

I finally managed to reach to Ubuntu after many unfair-unsolved errors and boot errors as well..

Now another unfair issue detected. I made an user account with password, great, I downloaded steam, I double click it, authenicator shows up but when I type something, it doesnt show on authenticator!!!

It wants a password for the user name account I use to let steam download packages, but when I type anything, it does not show on authenticator!It does do nothing but to say error that I typed nothing. I even deleted password of my username account and it still shows up. What the h!!! is this problem? Its even annoying than Justin Bieber!!

Authenticator is my next nightmare...How do I solve it?

Comment: Still shows it needs password

Comment: It doesn't show for security reasons, just type and pretend that it is actually showing - then press enter, If you forgot your password - http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem (authenticator ??? terminal ? graphical ?)  but in order to install anything the user must have administrator rights. To do so you must connect with your admin user (the first one you created) then go in user accounts application and give administrative rights to the new user.

Another problem I can think of is that you have enableb automatic login and you have an application that require administrative rights that starts right after login. You may check in the password wallet (just type key or password in the dash) you can then browse all the stored keys.

Comment: Great, just great, I forgot the password now because of all Ubuntu struggling issues making me feel dizzy...

Comment: The problem is simple to understand, authenticator is terminal. WHen I open steam, terminal shows to ask a password that I didnt even created a new because I removed the old, I try type anything, the typed word I typed, does not appear on terminal. Nothing happens, even if you type anything, it wont show on terminal..

Comment: in the terminal just type your password and hit enter. By default there's no feedback (like the ****** we are used to on the web)when typing a password in a terminal.